# Sharepoint online: Link to containing document set

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

On my Sharepoint online site I have a document library that contains document sets. The document sets allow a custom document type (inherited from document). In some cases I display the documents as a flat list (i.e. output includes documents from multiple document sets). In these instances I would like the user to be able to navigate to the document set that contains the document.

For example:
Document A is in Document Set 123 and document B is in Document Set 456. I have a view that shows both A and B. When the user looks at the details of A, there will be a link to 123. Similarly, when the user look at the details of B, there will be a link to 456.

I'd prefer an OOTB solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, there is not an OOTB way to achieve it.
As a workaround, we can add custom code below into script editor web part in DispForm.aspx page to achieve it.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var rootFolder=getUrlParameter("RootFolder");
    $("#documentset").append("<a href='"+rootFolder+"' target='_blank'>Link to Document Set</a>");
});
function getUrlParameter(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');
    var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)');
    var results = regex.exec(decodeURIComponent(location.search));
    return results === null ? '' : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
</script>
<div id="documentset"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this.

Here is the solution I came up with. Assume we are working with a content type called ct1 that inherits from documentSet and that document set

1. Create a document set content type that inherits from document set. For the purposes of this solution, we'll call it School.
2. Create a string field in School, we'll call it schoolName
3. Either manually or via workflow set schoolName = the name field of school
4. Create a content type of Student that inherits from Document
5. Add Student to the School Content Type
6. In the School content type Document Set Settings page make sure that schoolName is checked in the shared columns section
7. Create a document library (Schools) and add school content type
8. In schools add a new school
9. Open the new school and copy the url and paste it in a text editor
10. Remove the school name from the end of the URL
11. In the Student content type add a computed column (i.e. link to school)
12. Set the formula to =schoolName
13. Following the example at (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#create-clickable-actions) set the column formatting to:

{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "a",
   "txtContent": "@currentField",
   "attributes": {
      "target": "_self",
      "href": "='[URL copied from clipboard]' + @currentField"
   }
}

where [URL copied from clipboard] is the URL from step 9 (without the school name at the end)

You should now be able to add the calculated column to any view and it will link back to the parent folder

Answer (score 0):

Mike's answer works, but using the following href will allow creation of a reusable site column. I called mine “Container” so that it could be used generically with both folders and document sets. Also, if desired, you can shorten txtContext by removing the library name and trailing slash.

“href”: “=@currentWeb + ‘/’ + @currentField”

“txtContent”: “=substring(‘@currentField’, 1+indexOf(‘@currentField’,’/’), lastIndexOf(‘@currentField’,’/’))”

Find a more concise answer that includes a flow to capture the folder path at: https://sharepointstuff.com/2019/05/20/how-to-show-the-folder-path-of-a-file-in-library-views/comment-page-1/#modern

A "Container" column like this comes in handy when you're searching a document library, when you want to view the document set that contains the file you've found.